# What is meant by `import coding`?

Tags: python, import

I am working with `elffile` python module/library. There is one line of code that is giving the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "elffile.py", line 36, in <module>
    import coding
ImportError: No module named coding
```

I could not find any python file or class named `coding`. Also, I didn't find anything on the internet regarding `import coding`.

Comment: It means import the coding module. That's not part of the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html), you probably need to install it: `pip install coding`.

Comment: Thanks, @jonrsharpe. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Import is when you import modules to use in your coding.

If it cant find the module you probably have to install it. The easiest way to do this is to use pip.

Write: pip install coding (or pip3) and it will install the module.